# Crystal Reports Date by Year Comparison on a Running Total

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports XI R2.

My table has transaction data by date.  I have a group set up by day and a summary to give a count of transactions for each day.  I also have a running total set to give a year to date count for each day.  Of course it resets on a change in year.

My goal is to be able to find the difference between the YTD count yesterday and the same for the same date last year.

Edit:  I've misstated the goal.  It isn't to be able to find the difference for just yesterday, but for each day in a range of days.

Comment: What's your data source? Might be easier if the database can do some of the heavy lifting here.

Comment: Absolutely it would, but I'm still in a "probationary" period and don't have direct sql access to the db yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this nailed down.  There is likely a cleaner way of doing this, but....

I converted the dates (started as text yyyy-mm-dd) into text mm/dd/yyyy format:

```
stringvar yyyyear := {table.dateField}[1 to 4]; 
stringvar mmonth := {table.dateField}[6 to 7];;
stringvar dday := {table.dateField}[9 to 10];

mmonth + "/" + dday + "/" + yyyyear
```

Grouped by this field and inserted a count summary into the group header.  Created a separate field for the mm/dd portion of each date:

```
{@textDate}[1 to 5]
```

Added a flag to see if the date in the current group header matched the previous:

```
if previous({@mm/dd}) = {@mm/dd}
    then 1
else 0
```

Used a shared variable to store the YTD totals for each year (2 formulas):

```
shared numbervar totalsCurentYear;

if {@prevDateFlag} = 1 then 
    totalsCurrentYear := totalsCurrentYear + Sum ({@transactionCount}, {@textDate});

totalsCurrentYear
```

|

```
shared numbervar totalsLastYear;

if {@prevDateFlag} = 1 then 
    totalsLastYear := totalsLastYear + Sum ({@transactionCount}, {@textDate});

totalsLastYear
```

Put both of these into the group footer (suppressed) and added a field to do the subtraction into the group header.

Answer (score 0):

Create these two formula fields:

```
//{@LastYearToDate}
If {table.dateField} IN LastYearYTD Then
  1
Else
  0

//{@ThisYearToDate}
If {table.dateField} IN YearToDate Then
  1
Else
  0
```

Insert a summary on each field in the ReportFooter section.